# My code does not save the data form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble writing data to a page with a form. Below is how it looks and then, some of the code I am using:

[image]

```
    <section>
      <form method="POST" action="/teste/registro.php">
       <div class="container"> 
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="nome">Nome</label>
           <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="nome completo"class="form-control" required>

       </div>
       <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="nome">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="nome@email.com"class="form-control" required>

       </div>  
       <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
          <input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="telefone residencial" class="form-control" >

       </div>
       <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="telefone">Celular</label>
          <input  type="tel" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{5}-\d{4}$" name="celular" id="telefone" placeholder="telefone celular xx-xxxxx-xxxx" class="form-control" required>

       </div>      
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
          <textarea name="endereco" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> 

       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
          <input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder="assunto"class="form-control" required>

       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
          <textarea name="mensagem" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea> 
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>   

      </div>
      </form>
    </section>
    <footer>
    <footer>
```

this part I show my connection with the local bank:conexao.php

```
    <?php

      $servidor = "localhost";
      $usuario  = "root";
      $senha    = "";
      $dbname   = "contato";

      //criando a conexao com o banco
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
    ?>
```

I created the page to save form data in this way that follows:

```
    <?php

      include_once('conexao.php');
      $nome     = $_POST['nome'];
      $email    =$_POST['email'];
      $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
      $celular  = $_POST['celular'];
      $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
      $assunto  = $_POST['assunto'];
      $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

      $result_msg_contato = "INSERT INTO tbl_contato(nome, email, telefone, celular, endereco, assunto, mensagem, criada) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$celular', '$endereco', '$assunto', '$mensagem', NOW()) "; 
      $resultado_msg_contato = mysqli_query($conn,$result_msg_contato);  
   ?>
```

after you enter the data from the form and click on send the screen that appears is all white:

[[image: enter image image with the address after you click send here]]

Comment: did you check phpmyadmin to see if the data you entered is there?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a database client application. You seem to be writing your own client in PHP, so I don't see what PHPMyAdmin has to do with this.

Comment: I can't see what you posted failing, unless there are syntax errors/constraints we don't know about. Error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query will help you here. If that doesn't show anything, then that would suggest that you're trying to access as `file:///` rather than `http://localhost`, and/or you don't have a webserver/php/mysql installed. Plus, if there are any characters entered like apostrophes, then your query failed because of it.

Comment: When you click on submit, look at your html source and tell us what you see. You've also been given an answer and other comments. Up until that you come back here, we won't know what's happening; good luck with this.

Comment: Bom, SQL injection. I whish you no `O'Maley` will never ever register using your UI.

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong about phpmyadmin'm starting, I will explain my tenatr structure:
1- I have a page (registro.php), which has the form
2 did the page with the connection (conexao.php)
3- the page (registro.php) that has the form sends the data to another page that is salvaregistro.php
4- created after the connection with the bank and fill with the data in the form and click on save my screen is blank with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Title of the topic is misleading since this doesn't have anything to do with PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin is just a tool, GUI, for MYSQL.

Most likely, the problem is with the `INSERT` query but cannot tell since you're not using error reporting.

Try with the following:

```
<?php

      $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'contato');

    /* check connection */
    if (!$link) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
    }

      $nome     = $_POST['nome'];
      $email    = $_POST['email'];
      $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
      $celular  = $_POST['celular'];
      $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
      $assunto  = $_POST['assunto'];
      $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tbl_contato (`nome`, `email`, `telefone`, `celular`, `endereco`, `assunto`, `mensagem`, `criada`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssd', $nome, $email, $telefone, $celular, $endereco, $assunto, $mensagem);

    /* execute prepared statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

    /* close statement and connection */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: I will do what you gave me to solve tell you more I thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to help you out! Do you mind mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: I copied the code and did not change anything and appeared Error 404 Not Found,The requested URL /teste/teste.ico/salvaregistro.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at localhost Port 80          and nothing was recorded in the bank